# Batch file - Needs to replace commas too?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file (windows):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%j in (*.*) do (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename:.=_!
set filename=!filename: =_!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
```

This currently replaces spaces in filenames with underscores.

How can I add to that to also replace commas with underscores?

Thanks

J

Comment: I don't understand why you could not see the pattern and solve this on your own.

Comment: I don't understand why the purpose of your existence is going around making snarky comments when you could be spending that time helping people, especially when they are really polite about it.  Yeah, but there probably has to people like you around so that we know the difference between bloated egos and normal ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line:

```
set filename=!filename:,=_!
```